# HTML5 Fetch ignores <access origin="*"/> from cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cors

I am developing a Phonegapp app and use a library for data fetching. This library is using native "fetch" for getting data.

Unfortunately in Phonegap the native fetch seems to ignore my 
`<access origin="*"/>`
settings.

When I hack the isomorphic fetch library to force use the polyfill it works. But I think in general  should work with normal JS api such as fetch. Has someone found a better solution for this?

Comment: Did you find something in between ? I have the same problem. Could you post how do you force the isomorphic fetch to use polyfill ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I used the polyfill. And have actually changed the code. the polyfill, checks if fetch exists and if it already exists it does not overwrite it, so I removed that check.

Comment: I find a much simpler solution than hacking the library: if you make "self.fetch = null" before requiring the library then it inside will fine that no fetch is present and attaches the polyfill to self.fetch.